# Getting Azure Synapse pipeline run ID when running noteboot

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

How can I get Azure Synapse Pipeline run ID using python SDK in a synapse notebook? I have a ML pipeline that do a batch prediction everyday. What I want to do is get the pipeline run ID to save inside a DataFrame that is created in one of the notebook that I run in synapse.

I'm running my pipeline using the following major activities:

- notebook: I'm using a synapse notebook to read some parquet files from a blob preprocess using pandas and save again in another blob.

I saw that you can put a system variable in the file name with the pipeline run id. But I want to now if there is a way to get the current pipeline run id and my notebook is being executed using the azure python sdk

Comment: Please provide the information that what you have tried so far and how you are running ML pipeline from synapse?

Comment: I provide some more explanation to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the **Toggle parameter cell** option in **Synapse notebook cell**.

[image]

Use Toggle parameter cell option in synapse notebook cell and give any parameter name and assign any value to it. (**Here I have given empty string**).

In Notebook activity of pipeline, use **Base parameters and give same name and same data type** for it. In dynamic content of the parameter give `@pipeline().RunId` like below.

[image]

Execute this activity and Go to **Monitor-> Pipeline runs -> your pipeline-> Notebook activity snapshot** and you can see the output of the Notebook.

[image]

You can use this parameter in the Notebook as per your requirement.

Comment: You're indeed a god! Thank you my friend, this helped me  A LOT